# C# SSOM turn on List Rating settings

Tags: splist, settings, rating, ssom

I have been using the method described [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/bhushangawale/how-to-enable-and-disable-sharepoint-2010-rating-programmatically/) by attempting to use reflection to turn on the Rating Settings of a list. However, I get the following error:

Exception Message: `exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`

Stacktrace Message: `Value cannot be null.Parameter name: serviceContext`

Here is my attempt:

```
//Create the list
Guid id = web.Lists.Add("Board Name", "Board Desc", SPListTemplateType.DiscussionBoard);
web.Update();

//Retrieve the list I just created
SPList discBoardList = web.Lists[id];

//Attempt to turn on the Rating Settings for the newly created list
Type type = typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.RatingsSettingsPage);
MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod("EnableRatings", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { discBoardList, true }); //EXCEPTION THROWN
```

How do I resolve this issue? Or more importantly is there an easier/better way to turn on Rating Settings for a SharePoint list programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I just grab the default "Discussions List" that is created when creating a Community site. When I start adding the list items all numbers in `What's Happening` come out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

are you creating your list programmatically or it is generated using the OOTB options ?

if you are creating the list programmatically then you can use the below method to enable ratings in your list schema.

Add this to your default view (or any view you want) in Definition Schema of the List

```
<ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="AverageRating" />
          <FieldRef Name="RatingCount" />
  </ViewFields>
```

**Edit**

Follow [this link](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-provision-SharePoint-2010-Rating-columns-in-Content-Types.aspx)

You will have to create a content type containing the references of the ratings field and will have to add that content type in the list schema.

I am not very much sure about it but you can also try [This Link](http://www.sharemuch.com/2009/12/31/programaticaly-enable-rating-on-sharepoint-2010-lists/) as well and see if it solves your problem

Comment: Yes I am creating the list programmatically. Per your suggestion I tried:

`SPView view = discBoardList.DefaultView;
                            view.ViewFields.Add("AverageRating");
                            view.ViewFields.Add("RatingCount");
                            view.Update(); `

But go the `Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user` exception thrown. Please advise.

Comment: Do you have any control over the XML defined schema of the list.?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't.

Comment: have you seen the edit for the answer i made and checked both of the links in it ?

Comment: DId your issue got solved ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't been able to programmatically activate the ratings on the lists. For the time being, I am activating it manually, but is kind of tedious considering this is part of a migration tool which can consist of many lists.